# How to calculate matrix cumsum by condition in R?

Tags: r, matrix, cumsum

Lets say I have a 2x2 - matrix like:

[image]

and try to find the cumsum till position `[0,1]`, which would be `1+3 = 4`
or `[1,0]` which equals to `1+2 = 3`

So only the values, which matched the criteria, will be summed together..
Is there a function/method to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the sum of a leading block of a matrix? This is most straightforward if you work with numeric index. In case of character index (i.e., row names and column names), we can `match` for numeric index before doing `sum`.

```
mat <- matrix(1:4, 2, 2, dimnames = list(0:1, 0:1))

rn <- "0"; cn <- "1"
sum(mat[1:match(rn, rownames(mat)), 1:match(cn, colnames(mat))])
#[1] 4

rn <- "1"; cn <- "0"
sum(mat[1:match(rn, rownames(mat)), 1:match(cn, colnames(mat))])
#[1] 3
```

> Could you maybe explain to me why this code works?

In general, you can extract a block of a matrix `mat`, between rows `i1` ~ `i2` and columns `j1` ~ `j2` using `mat[i1:i2, j1:j2]`. A leading block means that the starting row and column are `i1 = 1` and `j1 = 1`. In your case, the terminating row and column are to be determined by names, so I do `match` to first find the right `i2` and `j2`.

I could sort of see your motivation. This is like selecting a region in an Excel sheet. :)

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility:

```r
m <- matrix(1:4,nrow=2)
m
#>      [,1] [,2]
#> [1,]    1    3
#> [2,]    2    4
pos <- c(1,0)
pos <- pos + 1
sum(m[1:pos[1],1:pos[2]])
#> [1] 3

pos <- c(0,1)
pos <- pos + 1
sum(m[1:pos[1],1:pos[2]])
#> [1] 4
```

Answer (score 2):

`cumsum` of the first column of the matrix `AsIs` then that of the `t`ranspose.

```
lapply(list(I, t), \(f) {r <- unname(cumsum(f(m)[, 1])); r[length(r)]})
# [[1]]
# [1] 3
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 4
```

---

*Data:*

```
m <- matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 4), 2, 2)
```